# Shared Element Transition with Floating Action Button studders

Tags: android, android-transitions, activity-transition

I have a `RecyclerView` with some cards each containing a mini Floating Action Button. When a card is clicked, the image on the card and the fab are used in a shared element transition.

When doing the return transition, the floating action button "snaps" back into its original position, rather than animating nicely as its supposed to.

Heres a gif that shows the issue: https://gfycat.com/SnappySeparateDeer

My code starting the activity and transition:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PlayActivity.class);

                Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create((View)holder.coverArt, "coverArt");
                Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create((View) holder.fab, "fab");
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                        makeSceneTransitionAnimation(mActivity, p1, p2);

                mContext.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

the mini fab on the cards:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/coverArt"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:transitionName="fab"/>
```

and the one in the activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/coverArt"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:transitionName="fab"/>
```

**EDIT:** I'd like to increase the bounty but it seems that feature isnt implemented in SO for some reason. I'm pretty sure I can add additional bounty points to the correct answer, so will add another +50. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @LukeSalamone the transition is not properly being aligned by the system. As you can see in the return transition, the fab animates back down but them snaps to the left to its original position, instead of the usual smooth transition.

Comment: Have you thought of using `overridePendingTransition()`?

Comment: Not sure how thats relevant. Are you suggesting to write a custom transition animation and override the one im already using?

Comment: It looks like the container in the activity with the listview is smaller than the one it transitions to. You'll need to change the fab's right margin in one of the activities.

Comment: The cards have a 12dp padding along with the fabs 16dp. This is the issue yes but the whole point is the transition framework usually takes care of this.

Comment: It looks to me like a different image is used for the FAB in each Activity. By default, the image scale type is passed between Activities, so the image will scale to the size of the FAB and then scale up to the final size in the target Activity. If so, you can solve this easily in two ways: use the same image so there is no scaling difference, or change the scale type in the target's enter SharedElementCallback.onSharedElementStart to FIT_START or something similar so that it doesn't scale at the start of the transition.

Comment: Yes, the fabs on the cards are using `app:fabSize="mini"`. I did try changing the size to normal but the issue still persists. For your second suggestion, i'm not currently defining any explicit scale types for the FABs, so im not sure if thats the issue. It seems like the issue is with the extra 12dp of total margins the FABS on the cards have, though not sure why.

Comment: Make sure you have same transition defined for windowSharedElementEnterTransition and windowSharedElementExitTransition. Can you also provide the transition definitions ? I'm asking because this seems like your exit transition starts from right edge of the screen, since the album image fits to width, we will not notice the same effect as seen in the fab.

Comment: @JavaGhost Heres a screenie of my styles: http://prntscr.com/berv06 and the defined transition: http://prntscr.com/bervbp

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping window and fragment exit/enter transition as described below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fade xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/" android:duration="500"/>
```

And shared element transitions as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:duration="500"
           android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_cubic">
    <changeBounds>
    <arcMotion
        android:maximumAngle="90"
        android:minimumHorizontalAngle="90"
        android:minimumVerticalAngle="0" />

    </changeBounds>
</transitionSet>
```

I'm not sure if anything other than ImageView has correct transition effects. I tried on a custom view I made last time and was getting similar issue while entering in transition, while return was perfect.

Comment: FAB extends ImageView. Anyway, this didnt seem to work, and im fairly certain `<changeImageTransform/>` is required.

Answer (score -2):

step: you are need to customize your detail layout, then transition animation work perfectly. like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="275dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:transitionName="picture"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/like"
            android:transitionName="fabButton"
            app:fabSize="normal" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Note: you customize size of layout and Images .

Comment: Im not sure how this is supposed to fix the issue. Could you explain your solution a bit?

Comment: please first you try this.